# Adding swipe down to dismiss on AVPlayerViewController in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to use `AVPlayerViewController` in SwiftUI which plays automatically and can be dismissed with swipe down. I figured out the auto-playback but the swipe-down to dismiss doesn't work and there seems to be no delegate method for it.

```swift
import AVKit
struct AVPlayerControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AVPlayerViewController

    let player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

Any idea how to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a coordinator and adding a swipe down gesture recognizer to the view controller's view. It's not the interactive swipe down I was aiming for but it's a start.

```swift
struct AVPlayerControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AVPlayerViewController

    class Coordinator {
        // MARK: Lifecycle

        init(_ parent: AVPlayerControllerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // MARK: Internal

        let parent: AVPlayerControllerView

        @objc func dismiss() {
            parent.dismiss()
        }
    }

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    let player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player
        vc.entersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins = true
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.dismiss))
        swipeDown.direction = .down

        vc.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
    }
}
```